# Richfaces AccordionItem resizing on selection

Tags: richfaces, accordion

I am working on a project with a dynamically created rich:accordion object with one or more accordionItems containing data tables of the same height.

When the page is first initialized, the open accordionItem is rendered correctly.  When I select another accordionItem, it is rendered, but then resized to be approximately 20 pixels smaller.  This cuts off data at the bottom of the accordionItem.

I have traced the problem down to the AJAX event used to populate the data in the accordion item.

```
<a4j:ajax event="enter" render="accordion" execute="@accordion" 
    listener="#{foo.doStuff}" > 
</a4j:ajax>
```

I have tried making changes to the contents of the render attribute (to accordionItem and extendedDataTable).  That fixes the resize problem, but I have to select the accordion item twice before the contents appear.

UPDATE 8/3:  I have confirmed that the HTML adds this attribute to the DIV element for the contents of the accordionItem when I change from the default one:
    style="height: 383px;"

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that changing to a different accordion item was changing the height for .rf-ac-itm-cnt, so I set the min-height property on that style in our .eccs file to be my desired height and that did the trick.